# Running into error 403 when testing flask API on python

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm able to test this file on Postman, however it is failing when I'm doing it on Python. I'm working behind a network proxy at the moment so I've specified the proxy.

This is the set of codes that I'm using:

```
# specify proxy
proxy = {'https':'https://username:password@01.2.345.6:1010', 
         'http':'http://username:password@01.2.345.6:1010'}

# specify content
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

# get input
testFile = open('test.json', 'r')
jsonInput = testFile.read()
requestJSON = json.loads(jsonInput)

# specify url
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/test'

response = requests.post(url, json=requestJSON, proxies=proxy, headers=header)
```

I'm getting a value of **403** when I check for the status code of `response`.

Comment: 403 error come when its forbidden means access denied. Check your details which you passing for authentication or check how you passing authentication header to api

Comment: @aviboy2006 I've checked the authentication details, they're correct! What do you mean by 'check how you passing authentication header to api' though?

Comment: in postman you are doing using authorisation or passing proxy ? You may be doing in postman using authorisation. Try this https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-make-an-API-call-with-basic-HTTP-authentication-using-Python

Comment: @aviboy2006 I'm doing neither of them but I'm able to get it to run on API hmm...

Comment: @aviboy2006 I've tried adding in the authentication details but I'm still getting the error 403 :/

Answer (score 2):

Error code 403 means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason. If it is working in postman then you can get exact python code of request library from postman and match it with your code to check the difference.

Comment: I copied the codes from postman and ran the codes but I'm still running into the same error :(

Comment: Recheck your headers.

Answer (score 0):

clearing browser cookies helped.
I am using Safari browser